# DistinctUntilChanged fires multiple times on multiple subscribers

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have one observable (`mainSequence`). If a condition is meet it should invoke an async method **once** until the condition changes. The methods return value will indicate success.

On failure I have a subscription which will inform the user.

Other observable are likely to subscribe to the `mainSequence` and have a similar error handling pattern.

But the consecutive observers to `mainSequence` will cause to invoke the `mainSequence` again. I only would like to have it invoked once hence my DistinctUntilChanged.

The example below outputs:

```
Working on 6
Working on 6
Working on 100
Working on 6
Working on 101
```

The output I want is:

```
Working on 6
Working on 100
Working on 101
```

I'm missing an reactive operator on my mainSequence, I just don't know which one.

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool IsNumberOk(int n) => n > 5;

    Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Working on {n}");
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    var mainSequence = Observable.Range(0, 10)
        .Where(IsNumberOk)
        .DistinctUntilChanged(IsNumberOk)
        .SelectMany(DoSomethingAsync);
    // sequence one error handling
    mainSequence.Where(x => !x).Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine($"Something went wrong with {nameof(mainSequence)}"));


    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var iTemp = 100 + i;
        var consecutive = mainSequence
            .Where(x => x) // if no error on mainSequence
           .Select(_ => iTemp)
           .DistinctUntilChanged()
           .SelectMany(DoSomethingAsync);
        consecutive.Where(x => !x).Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine($"Something went wrong with {iTemp}"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Publish()`  and `Connect()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstanding with regard to the distinction between an observable and a subscription. They are two distinct things.

The best parallel, in my mind, is that an observable is like a class and a subscription is like an instance of a class. Like a class, the observable is defined once. Each subscription is a new instance of the observable.

Let's take this code - somewhat cut-down from your code in the question.

```
Task<int> DoSomethingAsync(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Working on {n}");
    return Task.FromResult(-n);
}

IObservable<int> mainSequence =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 3)
        .SelectMany(DoSomethingAsync);
```

That's a single observable.

Now let's do this:

```
IDisposable mainSubscription1 =
    mainSequence
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"(1){nameof(mainSequence)}OnNext({x})"));

IDisposable mainSubscription2 =
    mainSequence
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"(2){nameof(mainSequence)}OnNext({x})"));
```

I have created two subscriptions, so I get two completely distinct instances of the observable. They run entirely separate of each other. In fact, `Observable.Range` outputs its values immediately, so each subscription blocks until it is complete. You get this output:

```
Working on 0
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(0)
Working on 1
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(-1)
Working on 2
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(-2)
Working on 0
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(0)
Working on 1
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(-1)
Working on 2
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(-2)
```

You can get `Observable.Range` to not block like this:

```
IObservable<int> mainSequence =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 3, Scheduler.Default)
        .SelectMany(DoSomethingAsync);
```

But you still have two completely independent instances of the observable running. You get something like this:

```
Working on 0
Working on 0
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(0)
Working on 1
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(0)
Working on 1
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(-1)
Working on 2
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(-1)
Working on 2
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(-2)
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(-2)
```

Now, if you want to share a single observable then you need to `Publish` it and `Connect` to the published observable to get the values flowing.

Here's the full code:

```
IConnectableObservable<int> mainSequence =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 3, Scheduler.Default)
        .SelectMany(DoSomethingAsync)
        .Publish();

IDisposable mainSubscription1 =
    mainSequence
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"(1){nameof(mainSequence)}OnNext({x})"));

IDisposable mainSubscription2 =
    mainSequence
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"(2){nameof(mainSequence)}OnNext({x})"));

IDisposable mainConnection =
    mainSequence
        .Connect();
```

Now when I run that, the two subscriptions don't start producing values until the `.Connect()` is called.

You get this:

```
Working on 0
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(0)
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(0)
Working on 1
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(-1)
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(-1)
Working on 2
(1)mainSequenceOnNext(-2)
(2)mainSequenceOnNext(-2)
```

Now if I had to get your code working, here's what it would look like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool IsNumberOk(int n) => n > 5;

    Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Working on {n}");
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    var mainSequence =
        Observable
            .Range(0, 10)
            .Where(IsNumberOk)
            .DistinctUntilChanged(IsNumberOk)
            .SelectMany(DoSomethingAsync)
            .Publish();
        
    mainSequence
        .Where(x => !x)
        .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine($"Something went wrong with {nameof(mainSequence)}"));

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var iTemp = 100 + i;
        var consecutive =
            mainSequence
                .Where(x => x)
                .Select(_ => iTemp)
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .SelectMany(DoSomethingAsync);
                
        consecutive
            .Where(x => !x)
            .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine($"Something went wrong with {iTemp}"));
    }

    IDisposable mainConnection =
        mainSequence
            .Connect();
}
```

It now produces this:

```
Working on 6
Working on 100
Working on 101
```